# Изменение кодировки таблицы

Tags: mysql

В таблице `user` столбцы в кодировке `latin1`, какой командой их можно изменить их кодировку на `utf8_general_ci` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE tableName CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: эта команда даст ожидаемый эффект только если и сами данные тоже находились в latin1

Comment: Команда дала ожидаемый еффект )